# jpql compare string as int

Tags: java, jpa, db2, jpql

I have object called `info`

```
class info
@Column(name="id")
int id
@Column(name="system")
string system
@Column(name="triesErrCount")
string triesErrCount
```

and same type in DB.
Now `triesErrCount` is `String` (in the class and in DB (varchar)), but in my db it's all like numbers ("1","7","56"...).

I try to get all infos that are less then 50, I try this:

`SELECT x from PaymentInfo x where  x.triesErr <=:triesErrAsString`

triesErrAsString = "50" in jpql

But it's not working, I also try:

```
class info
@Column(name="id")
int id
@Column(name="system")
string system
@Transient
string triesErrCount
@Column(name="triesErrCount")
int triesErrCountAsInt
```

`SELECT x from PaymentInfo x where  x.triesErr <=:triesErrAsInt`

triesErrAsInt = 50

But still not working. I'm using jpa 1.0. and OpenJPA 1.2.1

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_?

Comment: in my result i get all the infos  - include the infos.triesErrCount bigger the 50

Comment: and when you look at the log at the SQL invoked, rather than treating it like a magic black box?

Answer (score 1):

A string is not an Int, so numeric comparisons will not work as you are expecting.  You need to convert the string to a numeric to be able to use the numeric operators.  See [CAST](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_cast.htm)  for an example of how you might do that in JPQL, but you might be better off changing the type in the database to a numeric type.